# How do I get a parent attribute (e.g. a link) when the distinguishing information is in a later child?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

*Using **Selenium (Python)** to avoid spoilers of a soccer game*

I am trying to grab the url for a video of soccer match replay from a dynamically changing webpage. The webpage shows the score and I'd rather get the link directly, rather than visiting the website that almost certainly will show me the score. There are other related videos of the match, like 10 minute highlight reel. But I would like the full replay only.

There is a list of videos on the page to choose from. But the 'h1' heading indicating it's a full replay is wrapped inside the 'a' tag (see below). There are ~10 of these list items on the page but they are distinguished only from the content of 'h1', buried as child. The text that I'm after **Brentford v LFC : Full match**. The "full match" part is the give away.

**My problem is how do I get the link when the important information comes in a later child??**

```html
<li data-sidebar-video="0_5de4sioh" class="js-subscribe-entitlement">
  <a class="" href="//video.liverpoolfc.com/player/0_5de4sioh/">
    <article class="video-thumb video-thumb--fade-in js-thumb video-thumb--no-duration video-thumb--sidebar">
      <figure class="video-thumb__img">
        <div class="site-loader">
          <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
          </ul>
        </div> <img class="video-thumb__img-container loaded" data-src="//open.http.mp.streamamg.com/p/101/thumbnail/entry_id/0_5de4sioh/width/150/height/90/type/3" alt="Brentford v LFC : Full match" onerror="PULSE.app.common.VideoThumbError(this)" onload="PULSE.app.common.VideoThumbLoaded(this)"
          src="//open.http.mp.streamamg.com/p/101/thumbnail/entry_id/0_5de4sioh/width/150/height/90/type/3" data-image-initialised="true"> <span class="video-thumb__premium">Premium</span> <i class="video-thumb__play-btn"></i> <span class="video-thumb__time"> <i class="video-thumb__icon"></i> 1:45:07 </span>        </figure>
      <div class="video-thumb__txt-container"> <span class="video-thumb__tag js-video-tag">Match Action</span>
        <h1 class="video-thumb__heading">Brentford v LFC : Full match</h1> <time class="video-thumb__date">25th Sep 2021</time> </div>
    </article>
  </a>
</li>
```

My code looks like this at the moment. It gives me a list of the links but I don't know which one is which.

```
from selenium import webdriver

#------------------------Account login---------------------------#
#I have to login to my account first. 
#----------------------------------------------------------------#

username = "<my username goes here>"
password = "<my password goes here>"
username_object_id = "login_form_username"
password_object_id = "login_form_password"
login_button_name = "submitBtn"
login_url = "https://video.liverpoolfc.com/mylfctvgo"
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get(login_url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_id(username_object_id).send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_id(password_object_id).send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_name(login_button_name).click()

#--------------Find most recent game played----------------#
#I have to go to the matches section of my account and click on the most recent game
#----------------------------------------------------------------#
matches_url = "https://video.liverpoolfc.com/matches"
driver.get(matches_url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
latest_game = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/section/ul/li[1]/section/div/div[1]/a").get_attribute('href')
driver.get(latest_game)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

#--------------Find the full replay video----------------#
#There are many videos to choose from but I only want the full replay.
#--------------------------------------------------#

#prints all the videos in the list. They all have the same "data-sidebar-video" attribute 
web_element1 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('li[data-sidebar-video*=""] > a')

print(web_element1)

for i in web_element1:
    print(i.get_attribute('href'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a simple XPath locator since you are searching based on contained text.

```
//a[.//h1[contains(text(),'Full match')]]
^ an A tag
   ^ that has an H1 descendant
         ^ that contains the text "Full match"
```

NOTE: You can't just get the `href` from the A tag since it isn't a complete URL, e.g. `//video.liverpoolfc.com/player/0_5de4sioh/`. I would suggest you just click on the link. If you want to write it to a file, you'll have to append "https:" to the front of these partial URLs to make them usable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below.

Extract the list of videos with `li` tags, check if the `h1` tag inside the respective list has `Full match` if yes get the `a` tag with its `href`.

```
# Imports Required:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver.get("https://video.liverpoolfc.com/player/0_5j5fsdzg/?contentReferences=FOOTBALL_FIXTURE%3Ag2210322&page=0&pageSize=20&sortOrder=desc&title=Highlights%3A%20Brentford%203-3%20LFC&listType=LIST-DEFAULT")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//ul[contains(@class,'related-videos')]/li")))
videos = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[contains(@class,'related-videos')]/li")

for video in videos:
    option = video.find_element_by_tag_name("h1").get_attribute("innerText")
    if "Full match" in option:
        link = video.find_element_by_tag_name("a").get_attribute("href")
        print(f"{option} : {link}")
```

```
Brentford v LFC : Full match : https://video.liverpoolfc.com/player/0_5de4sioh/
```

Comment: I really liked this response and used it combination with @JeffC's response to create a final set of code that works every time - I'll post it below. I found that this solution worked most of the time and I'm unsure why. But that was the case nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `driver.execute_script` to grab only the links that have the "Full match" designation as a child:

```
links = driver.execute_script('''
 var links = [];
 for (var i of document.querySelectorAll('li[data-sidebar-video*=""] > a')){
    if (i.querySelector('h1.video-thumb__heading').textContent.endsWith('Full match')){
        links.push(i.getAttribute('href'));
    }
 }
 return links;
''')
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, however, I am currently using Python and was unable to test this solution. Someone else will benefit from this proposed solution so I appreciate your time for that reason as well :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked. I used both @JeffC's and @pmadhu's responses to get a stable/working code. I also added a headless option so you can run the code without having to view the webpages, which inadvertently might show you the score you're trying to avoid! As a result I had to remove the two lines of wait code, which I've just commented out in case you want to keep it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

#------------------------Account login---------------------------#
#Logs into my account
#----------------------------------------------------------------#

username = "" #<----my username goes here
password = "" #<----my password goes here
username_object_id = "login_form_username"
password_object_id = "login_form_password"
login_button_name = "submitBtn"
login_url = "https://video.liverpoolfc.com/mylfctvgo"

#headless option is added so that this can operate in the background.
headless_option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
headless_option.add_argument("headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver", options=headless_option)
driver.get(login_url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_id(username_object_id).send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_id(password_object_id).send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_name(login_button_name).click()

#--------------Find most recent game played----------------#
#Clicks on the match section of my account and clicks on the most recent game
#----------------------------------------------------------------#
matches_url = "https://video.liverpoolfc.com/matches"
driver.get(matches_url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
latest_game = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/section/ul/li[1]/section/div/div[1]/a").get_attribute('href')
driver.get(latest_game)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

#--------------Find the full replay video----------------#
#There are many videos to choose from but I only want the full replay of the most recent game.
#--------------------------------------------------#

#institutes a maximum wait time for the page to load; I could have a slow connection one day. 
#wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
#wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//a[.//h1[contains(text(),'Full match')]]")))

#finds the full match link using an xpath search term, which is in the brackets
full_replay_xpath_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[.//h1[contains(text(),'Full match')]]")
#gets the value from the 'href' attribute 
full_match_link = full_replay_xpath_element.get_attribute('href')

#finds the game title so I know what match relates to link I'm getting. 
match_title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[contains(text(),'Full match')]")
#gets the value using innerText
match_title_innertext = match_title.get_attribute("innerText")

#prints both the game title and the link. 
print(f"{match_title_innertext} : {full_match_link}")

#An example output is: 
#Porto v LFC: Full match : https://video.liverpoolfc.com/player/0_i6064wb1/
```